# Easy Autocomplete nested Json structure

Tags: javascript, easyautocomplete

I'm having a hard time to structure the list location for items array in order to access name attribute in search.js 
Below is the nested JSON structure:

```
{
  menus: [
    {
     name: "Summer ",
     url: "/menus/2",
     items: [
       {
         name: "man o man", //this is what I'm trying to access
         url: "/menus/2/items/7"
       }
     ]
  ]
}
```

So far I've tried in search.js:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $input = $("[data-behavior='autocomplete']")

  var options = {
     getValue: "name",
     url: function(phrase) {
       data = "/search.json?q=" + phrase;
       return data;
     },
     categories: [
      {
        listLocation: "menus",
        header: "--<strong>Menus</strong>--",
      },
      {
        listLocation: "items", //this is where I'm having problem with 
        header: "--<strong>Items</strong>--",
      }
    ],
    list: {
       onChooseEvent: function() {
         var url = $input.getSelectedItemData().url
         $input.val("")
         Turbolinks.visit(url)
       }
    }
  }

  $input.easyAutocomplete(options)
})
```

Comment: How is this related to ruby-on-rails? can you detail out more please?

Comment: I'm working with Rails 6. But you're right, I didn't need to use that in the title. Updated!